# Coding Standards for Gremlin/Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

We are in the process of developing a review tool for Gremlin/Cypher as we predominantly work with Neo4j graph databases in our project to reduce the manual review effort and also deliver quality code.

Are there any list of coding standards(formatting/performance tips etc.,) for Gremlin and Cypher scripts which can be used as a checklist for performing review of these scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find one specific answer, as discussing coding standards can lead to very subjective (and debate-laden) answers. That said: I'll go with something more objective:

First step would be to decide on Gremlin vs Cypher since they're not the same thing nor the same style. When making that decision (and maybe that decision is *use both*), you should really take a close look at Neo4j 2.0 development (currently at Milestone 4), as Cypher is maturing rapidly and there's a lot of work being put into it, both from expressiveness point of view and performance point of view.

Assuming you go with Cypher, I'd suggest you look at the samples being published by Neo Technology, especially the [Cypher learning module](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher). I don't know of any published guidelines, but I'd think most of the guidelines would be similar to any scripting guidelines you already have (such as naming conventions, spacing, etc.). Going further, you're likely going to use Cypher via code as well as through the console. So you'll want to continue using your traditional programming style guidelines, as well as specifying the language-specific library you'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

I can only give you an answer related to Gremlin.  First, it is important to note that almost all examples, in the Gremlin [wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki), [GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.com/), the [gremlin-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users) mailing list, etc. are meant for the REPL.  Example traversals from these sources tend to be lengthy one-liners, that are written that way for easy transfer via copy/paste to the command line for execution.  It is somewhat satisfying to get your answer in one-line in the REPL, but for production code that requires maintenance over time, consider avoiding the temptation to do so, unless there is some specific reason that dictates it.

Second, from a style/formatting perspective, Gremlin is a DSL built on Groovy.  Whatever style you like for Groovy should generally work for Gremlin.  Start with the Groovy [recommendations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers) and tweak them to your needs/liking.  I would expect that a tool like [CodeNarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/) would help with general style checks and identifying common Groovy coding problems.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the message from the mailing list [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/coding$20standards/neo4j/JYz2APHV-_k/V1BKRwyv5hAJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/coding%2420standards/neo4j/JYz2APHV-_k/V1BKRwyv5hAJ)